# PromQL Requests per minute

Tags: grafana, prometheus, promql

I'm trying to create a graph of total `POST` requests per minute in a graph, but there's this "ramp up" pattern that leads me to believe that I'm not getting the actual total of requests per minute, but getting an accumulative value.

Here is my query:

```
sum_over_time(django_http_responses_total_by_status_view_method_total{job="django-prod-app", method="POST", view="twitch_webhooks"}[1m])
```

Here are the "ramp up" patterns over 7days (drop offs indicating a reboot):
[image]

What leads me to believe my understanding of `sum_over_time()` is incorrect is because the existing webhooks should always exist. At the time of the most recent reboot, we have 72k webhook subscriptions, so it doesn't make sense for the value to climb over time, it would make more sense to see a large spike at the start for catching webhooks that were not captured during downtime.

Is this query correct for what I'm trying to achieve?

I am using django-prometheus for exporting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want `increase` rather than `sum_over_time`, as this is a counter.

Comment: I did think so as well, thanks for confirming. An issue I see, though, is this same ramp up trend, and if I look over the last 24 hours it accumulates all the way as far as 100k+ per minute which is definitely inaccurate. I simply used the same query as above using increase() rather than sum_over_time(), is that correct?

Comment: Accepting answer. Appears my actual issue is that there are multiple instances of Prometheus spawning somehow which cause these fluctuations when being treated as a single target.

Answer (score 0):

If the `django_http_responses_total_by_status_view_method_total` metrics is a [counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter), then [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function must be used for returning the number of requests during the last minute:

```
increase(django_http_responses_total_by_status_view_method_total[1m])
```

Note that `increase()` function in Prometheus can return fractional results even if `django_http_responses_total_by_status_view_method_total` metric contains only integer values. This is due to implementation details - see [this comment](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/1215#issuecomment-850305711) and [this article](https://medium.com/@romanhavronenko/victoriametrics-promql-compliance-d4318203f51e) for details.

If the `django_http_responses_total_by_status_view_method_total` metric is a [gauge](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#gauge), which shows the number of requests since the previous sample, then [sum_over_time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum_over_time) function must be used for returning requests per last minute:

```
sum_over_time(django_http_responses_total_by_status_view_method_total[1m])
```